# C++ trouble with Exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I'm having trouble with exceptions in C++ involving the structure of the exceptions and how arguments are passed and whatnot.

From this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

1)When you throw something, for example: `throw 20;`, are you passing `20` to `int e`, and if so, what's the point of throwing an integer to catch if you only respond by typing out a command to give the screen?

2) If the program runs into an exception and throws something, does the program then go to catch to fix the issue in the program, or does the program go to catch just to respond that an error has occurred and that you need to fix that program.

3)Looking at the standard exception section: are the exceptions shown at the bottom (`bad_alloc`, `bad_cast`, `bad_exception`,... etc) supposed to be types of exceptions that can be passed to a variable? Like would you say `catch(bad_exception& e)` and the only thing that `e` could receive is a number/float/character that doesn't fit any other exception types? Honestly, I'm very confused with standard exceptions.

4) In standard exceptions, again, is `exceptions` in `class myexception: public exception` a constructor?

Sorry for the long post. Any online tutorials to simplify the topic, advice, or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Your post suggests that you did not quite understand the concepts of _type_ (and _class_), _object_, and _variable_, yet. I would work on this before trying to grasp how exceptions work.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be above your level, but I hope it at least gives you a basic understanding of what happens when an exception is thrown. And it will give you some googleable terms at the very least.

A `throw` statement is not an immediate function call. It is a point in a program where a certain object is constructed (be it an `int`, `std::exception`, `std::runtime_error`, or *any* other type of object).

After the exception object is constucted, the stack is unwound. This is an important concept and I will try to sketch it in a few words. Unwinding the stack means all the functions you have called are traversed in reverse order, and all objects allocated (on the stack) in those functions are destructed. This process continues backwards until a `catch` block is reached that catches your type of exception (normal function overload resolution rules apply here, so conversions are possible).

An illustrative example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class my_exception
{
public:
  my_exception(const std::string& message) : message(message) {}
  const std::string& what() { return message; }
private:
  const std::string message;
};

void boo()
{
  int local = 5; // local, "automatic storage duration" variable
  throw my_exception("boo threw");
}
void bam()
{
  int* i = new int(42); // dynamically allocated int, unowned, accessible
  std::unique_ptr<int> j(new int(43)); // dynamically allocated int, owned by a smart pointer with automatic storage duration
  boo();
  delete i;
}

void f()
{
  try
  {
    bam();
  }
  catch(const my_exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }
}

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

The process that perspires is the following:

1. `main` is entered
2. `f()` is called
3. `try` block is entered
4. `bam()` is called
5. an `int` is dynamically allocated. A pointer to `int` named `i` with automatic storage duration is constructed (on the stack)
6. a `unique_ptr` object containing a pointer to another dynamically allocated `int` is created.
7. `boo()` is called
8. An `int` with automatic storage duration in constructed.
9. An object of type `my_exception` is constructed and stack unwinding begins.
10. `boo()` is left, and `local` is destructed (cleaned up)
11. we're back in `bam()` and also leaving it behind: first `j`'s destructor is called, which calls `delete` on the integer with value `43`. Then the pointer object `i` is destructed, but the integer it pointed to is not `delete`d. We have a memory leak (the `delete i;` statement is never reached).
12. we're back in `f()`, where a friendly `catch` catches our `my_exception` and outputs the `message` though `std::cout`.

To answer your questions:

1) No, a more complex process happens, which eventually ends in step 12 which might *resemble* a function call, but it is not really.

2) See above.

3) A `catch` "receives" an object. It works much like function overloads. The best one is picked. If there is no match, unwinding continues. `e` doesn't "receive" anything. It might be constructed from whatever is thrown, but that requires that the type of `e` has the right conversion/constructor.

4) No. That specifies inheritance. Example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class my_exception : public std::exception
{
public:
  my_exception(const std::string& message) : std::exception(message) {}
}
```

This `my_exception` class inherits the `what()` function defined in `std::exception`, so I don't need to define it myself.

Comment: @rubenvb To be honest, I don't understand stack unwinding at all. And how exceptions are evaluated is even more confusing to me. I'm in the very beginning stages of C++. So if you could point me to a place where this is simplified, that'd be great.I have a lot of questions, and I feel like the questions I have would far exceed the amount of characters that I'm allowed to type.

Comment: @TranslucentDragon Search about stack (not the data structure), function call in C/C++. That's an important mechanism you need to understand one day.